# How to stop Screen reader to reads all errors span tag which has role="alert"?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, wai-aria, jaws-screen-reader

I am using Chrome Vox Screen reader for my mobile application. This reader reads all errors span tag which has `role="alert"`, I want screen reader should read only first error(role='alert'). For example we can see Gmail account registration page. How can I achieve this scenario?

Comment: are you looking for attr selector ? https://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/ i.e $( "[role='alert']" ) ?

Comment: you should add attribute role='alert' in the run time for required elements.

Comment: A11y reads only first role='alert' element even though many div elements exists. A11y reads only last role='alert' element even though many span elements exists. So you can try by changing span to div so it reads only the first element.

Answer (score 1):

If you are putting spans next to each input on error these shouldn't really have role=alert but rather IDs. Then the inputs would want to have aria-describedby= that ID. You would want to possibly have a message alert that says there were errors and either focus there or focus on the first error related input, select, etc.

If you want an error box at the top of the form and would like a summary you can focus there on error and make a listing with anchors (text explaining error) pointing to the inputs. No alert role is needed for this.

If you just want to alert users that there were errors you can put a phrase saying this in a container with role=alert and aria-live=assertive and then focus on the first input error.

Comment: thanks Nick, I am trying with aria-describeby attribute. It's working fine as I required. But if we navigate to another input control in the form and come back again to same input which has aria-describedby, it does not read second time.

Comment: I would note that ChromeVox is not a very common screen reader for true end users. It has been noted that it isn't as good on features for aria, etc. 
http://webaim.org/discussion/mail_thread?thread=5758
http://webaim.org/projects/screenreadersurvey6/
.3% of respondents from the current surveys from webaim noted using ChromeVox.on Desktop and it is not listed for mobile devices. 

Currently the main contenders for mobile:
VoiceOver 56.7%
TalkBack for Android 17.8%
Nuance Talks 4.5%

Answer (score 0):

I had to solve the same problem and the best solution was to not use `role=alert` for the error messages at all. Instead, use `aria-describedby` for elements which can be validated and point it to the span containing the error message.

This will ensure that the error message for an **element in focus** is read.

This approach is more user friendly comparing to alerts because the error messages are not read at once (as described in the question) which might be confusing. The error message of an element in focus is read instead while navigating through a page.

Example:

```html
      <div> 
         <input type="text" 
                    name="username" 
                    id="username" 
                    aria-describedby="username_error"
                    aria-invalid="true"/> 
          <span class="error" id="username_error">Username is unknown</span> 
      </div>
```

A few more tips:

- Get a hint to screen reader that an element contains errors by setting `aria-invalid=true` attribute
- ARIA 1.1 defines 'aria-errormessage' attribute which could be used instead of `aria-describedby` as soon as it's widely [adopted](https://a11ysupport.io/tests/tech__aria__aria_errormessage_with_aria_invalid_true)

Comment: aria-describedby will work when screen reader will focus that element. Screen reader is generally used by blind or color blindness people, and the purpose of giving alert on screen load so user can know what is the error in minimum effort, else user has to go through all elements and then user will find error element.